Changing a column name in delta live streaming table
Is it possible to change a column name in a Delta live streaming table once the table has been created.
I have attempted a map function but had no success. Has anyone experienced this or have any advice for solving this thanks in advance

I don't think you can change the column name of a DLT once it has been created. But what you can do is run a full refresh which will recreate/rebuild the table from scratch. Before refreshing, update the code so the final table has the corrected column names.
